# How to revert Inspect Element to its old style?

Tags: firefox, web-development

Recently (in version 19 or 20, I think), Firefox's Inspect Element has changed. Before, it had a nice layout in an inverted L shape that allowed me to see a lot of the styles on the right-hand side. Now, they changed that. Like Firebug and other browsers' similar tools, it's become a single bar in the bottom. This is positive in that it doesn't change the page's width, but when I needed the page's width to stay stable, I used Firebug.

Now, the new layout is everything but practical to me. The styles section is really small, so I can't see much of it, and searching through it is a pain.

I would like to **revert Inspect Element to the layout it had before**: the inverted L. I know I could just install an older version of the browser, but that would leave me stuck behind regarding browser evolution and compatibility in the future. So I would like to know if there's a way to change only that function, **keeping Firefox 20.0.1**.

Firefox version: 20.0.1

OS: Windows 8 professional x64

The old interface I want back:

[image]

The new interface:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem appear after this
[Merging Firebug into the built-in Firefox Developer Tools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/02/08/merging-firebug-into-the-built-in-firefox-developer-tools/)

and I installed the last version before  Version 2.0.17
[Firebug Version History](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/?page=1#version-2.0.17) for solve it,
and firebug returned to my favorite version